# Python threading.Thread() returns NoneType?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on a small application that I know will have 3 threads independent from the main thread, at some point, and I will need to identify a thread from another. Suppose threads are `A`, `B`, `C`. `A` will need to join with `C` if something happens. I am trying to add the threads to a dictionary before starting them, so I can identify thread `C` later:

```
currentThreads['A'] = threading.Thread(target=func, args=[]]).
currentThreads['A'].start()
currentThreads['B'] = threading.Thread(target=func, args=[]).start()
currentThreads['B'].start()
```

The behavior is weird: sometimes both `currentThreads[key].start()` yield `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'`, sometimes only `currentThreads['B'].start()` does.

Any clue why this might happen?

Comment: Why you are starting `B` thread two times?

Comment: Damn. No idea what I did there :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to you, for keeping reference name to your threads, to actually give them names, like so:

```
t = threading.Thread(name='my_service', target=func)
```

Then when you need to check for the name of the thread, just get it's name with `getName()`:

```
current_thread_name =  threading.currentThread().getName()
```

Comment: A suggestion, since someone else might be looking into how they can access other threads from within the current one. It's worth checking out `threading.enumerate` which will return a list of the threads currently alive - you can identify the one you need by the name you set above.

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) returns `None` so in:

```
currentThreads['B'] = threading.Thread(target=func, args=[]).start()
```

`currentThreads['B']` is `None` thus calling  `currentThreads['B'].start()` will raise `AttributeError`

Comment: True, didn't notice I was calling `start` twice